# Does Cortana support audio file reading?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app, cortana, windows-10-mobile

I want to develop a Bluetooth voice input device and it shall send voice over Bluetooth Gatt to WP. the format shall ended up as a wav file. and Cortana needs to react the command in the wav file.

Is Cortana supporting this?

Comment: If your device will just be recognized as a Bluetooth microphone, it's probably going to just work, but you cannot do anything with Cortana except adding voice commands.

Answer (score -2):

Did you try DispatcherTimer?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer.aspx It should work